# Prove if this is a linear order or if it not a linear order on $\mathbb N$?

Tags: relations, order-theory

$S=\{ (m,n):m,n \in \mathbb N, m \leq n, m \neq 5\} \cup \{(m,5): m \in \mathbb N\}$.

I have this definition: A partial order $R$ on $A$ is called a linear order (or total order) on $A$ if for any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $A$, either $(x,y) \in R$ or $(y,x) \in R$. But it is not very clear to me.

I believe this is not a linear order because $(1,5)$ is not related to $(4,5)$, but not really sure how to prove this.

Comment: All it really means to be a linear order is either $x < y$ or $y < x$ (or both). But it doesn't seem like you've actually provided a linear order. It looks like you've only given us a set.

Comment: @Zelzy this is all they gave me.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The thing is that you can impose multiple partial orders on any given set (except I guess something trivial like the empty set or the set of one element). Sometimes you can just give a set if the order is clear from context. (E.g. you don't have to give the order on $\mathbb R$ since it is so standard). In this case, though, it seems they were supposed to give you a partial order, unless they are expecting you to assume it is something like, e.g., the dictionary order.

Comment: Wait, I might have misread the question. Is $S$ your relation on $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Zelzy Yes it is on the natural numbers.

Comment: My mistake. Oops.

Comment: Well, first off you aren't interested if $(1,5)$ or $(4,5)$ are "related" since we are looking at a relation on $\mathbb N$. You want to show that if $m,n$ are natural numbers then either $(m,n)\in S$ or $(n,m)\in S$. (or find a counterexample).

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47968/discussion-between-jwigz-and-zelzy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me this is a linear ordering on $\mathbb{N}$.
Let us say $S = S_1 \cup S_2$, where $S_1 = \{ (m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : m \leq n,\, m \neq 5 \}$ and $S_2 = \{ (m,5) : m \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Let us see it is a partial ordering.
**Reflexivity.** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
If $n\neq 5$ then $(n,n) \in S_1$ because $n \leq n$;
$(5,5) \in S_2$.
**Anti-symmetry.** Suppose $(m,n), (n,m) \in S$.
If $n=5$ then from $(5,m) \in S$ we conclude that $m=5$ (analogous for $m=5$);
if $m,n \neq 5$ then $m \leq n \leq n$ and thus $m=n$.
**Transitivity.** Suppose $(m,n),(n,p) \in S$.
If $p=5$ then $(m,p) \in S_2 \subseteq S$;
if $p \neq 5$ then $(n,p) \notin S_2$, thus $(n,p) \in S_1$ and $n \neq 5$ and with the same reasoning $m \neq 5$, so that we have $m \leq n \leq p$, whence $m \leq p$ and $(m,p) \in S$.

Let us now show that this ordering is linear.
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.
If $m,n \neq 5$ then either $m \leq n$ whence $(m,n) \in S_1 \subseteq S$ or $n \leq m$ and $(n,m) \in S_1 \subseteq S$;
if $n = 5$ then $(m,n) = (m,5) \in S_2 \subseteq S$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the symbol $\le_S$ to denote the order specified by $S$, to distinguish it from the usual order on $\mathbb N$, for which we'll use the standard $\le$ symbol.

If  $m$ and $n$ are two elements of $\mathbb N$, $$m \le_S n$$ precisely when $$(m,n) \in S$$ It's really just a different notation, but I find it makes it easier to think about.

So let's look at the two sets that make up $S$. The first part, $$\{ (m,n):m,n \in \mathbb N, m \leq n, m \neq 5\}$$
says that so long as $m$ isn't the number 5 $$m \le_S n \iff (m,n) \in S \iff m \le n$$ i.e., so long as there are no fives involved it looks just like our usual order on $\mathbb N$.

The second part $$\{(m,5): m \in \mathbb N\}$$ says that $m \le_S 5$ for all numbers $m$.

Hopefully that gives you a better image of the order determined by $S$. To me it looks like they took the usual order but plucked out 5 and stuck it out at positive infinity, so I suspect it is a total order (though I haven't checked it explicitly). Because the set $S$ is defined with two parts, if you want to prove that it's a total order you'll have to break it down by cases, depending on whether or not $x$ is equal to 5 and whether or not $y$ is equal to 5, which will give you 2*2 = 4 cases.

Note that you are probably required to prove the partial order properties (reflexivity, anti-symmetry, and transitivity) too, and you'll have to do $'= 5'$ and $'\ne 5'$ cases for those as well.

Comment: So the cases are(1) x=5 and y=5, and(2) x=5 and y $\neq$ 5, and(3) x$\neq$5 and y=5, and (4)x $\neq$5 and y $\neq$5.

Comment: Yes, when you are proving that it is a total order.

Comment: Reflexivity only has one variable so you just have 2 cases. And proving Transitivity, with x, y, and z, will have 2*2*2 cases. Hopefully some of those cases will be impossible, or can use similar arguments to another case.